# How to I preg_match_all starts with "http" and ends with (") or (') or white space(tabs, space, line break)

Tags: php, preg-match-all

How do I write in regex that preg_match_all starts with "http"(without quotes) and ends with (") or (') or white space(tabs, space, line break)

I want to preg_match_all all the parts just starting with "http"

```
Wupload
http://www.wupload.com/file/CCCCCCC/NNIW-LiBRARY.part1.rar
http://www.wupload.com/file/VVVVVVVV/NNIW-LiBRARY.part2.rar
http://www.wupload.com/file/TTTTTTT/NNIW-LiBRARY.part3.rar

Fileserve
http://www.fileserve.com/file/WWWW/NNIW-LiBRARY.part1.rar
http://www.fileserve.com/file/TTTTT/NNIW-LiBRARY.part2.rar
http://www.fileserve.com/file/RRRRR/NNIW-LiBRARY.part3.rar

Uploaded.To
http://ul.to/AAAA/NNIW-LiBRARY.part1.rar
http://ul.to/BBBBB/NNIW-LiBRARY.part2.rar
http://ul.to/YYYYYY/NNIW-LiBRARY.part3.rar
```

Results must be like this
http://www.wupload.com/file/CCCCCCC/NNIW-LiBRARY.part1.rar
http://www.wupload.com/file/VVVVVVVV/NNIW-LiBRARY.part2.rar
http://www.wupload.com/file/TTTTTTT/NNIW-LiBRARY.part3.rar
http://www.fileserve.com/file/WWWW/NNIW-LiBRARY.part1.rar
http://www.fileserve.com/file/TTTTT/NNIW-LiBRARY.part2.rar
http://www.fileserve.com/file/RRRRR/NNIW-LiBRARY.part3.rar
http://ul.to/AAAA/NNIW-LiBRARY.part1.rar
http://ul.to/BBBBB/NNIW-LiBRARY.part2.rar
http://ul.to/YYYYYY/NNIW-LiBRARY.part3.rar

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I have tried 
$result = preg_split('/\bhttp:\/\/[\d.a-z-]+[]\d!"#$%&\'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\\\\_`a-z{|}~^-]*/i', $subject);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i suggest you use parse_url to fetch parts of urls!
Take a look at php.net

**EDIT :**

```
$file = file_get_contents( YOUR FILE NAME );
$lines = explode("\r\n", $file);
foreach( $lines as $line ){
$urlParts = parse_url( $line );
if( $urlParts['scheme'] == 'http' ){
 // Do anything ...
}
}
```

**CHANGE :**

oOk, i don't know what's your code!if you want to scrape html to find links i suggest this to you, it return href values of a tag to you :

```
preg_match_all ( "/<[ ]{0,}a[ \n\r][^<>]{0,}(?<= |\n|\r)(?:href)[ \n\r]{0,}=[ \n\r]{0,}[\"|']{0,1}([^\"'>< ]{0,})[^<>]{0,}>((?:(?!<[ \n\r]*\/a[ \n\r]*>).)*)<[ \n\r]*\/a[ \n\r]*>/ is", $source, $regs );

for ( $x = 0; $x < count ( $regs [ 1 ] ); $x ++ ) {
$tmp_array [ "link_raw" ] = trim ( $regs [ 1 ] [ $x ] );
}
```

**Then use parse_url to check thoes**

Comment: parse_url is not the thing I want. It can be used after extracting the url but I want to extract all urls in a given text.

Comment: it's not problem! take a look at my answer!

Comment: thanks for reply but there are no lines because the source is html code. So I have to write it as preg_match_all starts with (http) and ends with (") or (') or white space(tabs, space, line break)  
Do you have a suggestion for that?

Comment: the problem is that I can't use just "href" because some links are given in normal text. So I have to find strings starting with "http"

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you would like to remove the "Wupload", "Fileserve" and "Uploaded.To" titles and capture just the URLs in an array?  If so, try the following:

```
preg_match_all('!^http://.*\n!m', $string, $matches);
echo "<pre>" . print_r($matches, 1) . "</pre>";
```

Comment: Actually, this is a html source code but I can't put it right to the post. By the way your code isn't working. You can check it from http://myregextester.com/index.php

Comment: @rasputin: Why can't you put it "right to the post"? If you don't provide your actual input, then we can't give you the actual solution.

Comment: because of writing format of stackoverflow. I tried all the opportunities in the post menu(blockquoute, pre, code) but nothing helped me...

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
<?php
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('@https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?@', $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    // Do your processing here.
}
?>
```

Comment: gives me error - Unknown modifier '/'
Can you correct it, please?